# Spawn multiple objects in gazebo

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there,

I'm recently started with ROS and now I'm trying to work with the gazebo simulator.

My question: How can a spawn an object, for example the blue box in the gazebo tutorials, more than one time (on different positions)?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/52115/spawn-multiple-objects-in-gazebo/) by [Webo](https://answers.ros.org/users/3960/webo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2013-01-13

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In gazebo you can re-use the same urdf to spawn the same object at different places by using different model names.

```
rosrun gazebo spawn_model -urdf -file box.urdf -model box1 -x 1.0 -y 1.0 -z 1.0

rosrun gazebo spawn_model -urdf -file box.urdf -model box2 -x 4.0 -y 4.0 -z 1.0
```

---

Originally posted by [prasanna.kumar](https://answers.ros.org/users/2416/prasanna.kumar/) with karma: 1363 on 2013-04-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6